# How to calculate quadruplet reference (east, west, north, south) of a parcels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5

I faced a challenge to calculate which parcels are located in east, west, north, south of a definite parcel?

I mean that when I select a feature, how to calculate that which feature is located in east or west ... of this feature?

In this picture, I want to calculate which feature is located to east and which feature is located in west?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this routine:

Find leftmost point for convex hull of original.
Draw very long line heading down from that point.
Repeat with rightmost point.
Iterate through immediate neighbors of original polygon and check if one of above 2 lines will split them in two or more. If yes, add this neighbor to the list of parcels South of original.

Apply similar procedure to other directions.

Comment: sorry, can you clarify it a little bit more!